# HTML Link Dropping the Anchor Part

Tags: html, anchor

I have a link on a page like this

```
use our <a href="about-us.php#contactform">contact form</a>.
```

Then in about-us.php I have

```
<div class="extra" id="contactform">
```

When I click the link, the browser takes me to the correct page BUT

The address bar momentarily flashes up "about-us.php#contactform"

Then it falls back to "about-us.php#" and the browser doesn't move to the anchor.

This is so simple, yet I can't see what is causing it. I have several other anchors with exactly the same format that are working. I also have a link that is called from PHP to the same anchor, and that works.

Mystified!

PROBLEM SOLVED

It was the PHP and Javascript bit of the overall page code that caused the problem. It was overriding the anchor link. Having wrapped the javascript in a PHP if() statement, it is under control.

Moral of the story: look at everything and not just the bits close to the apparent problem.

Comment: Not sure what is causing your error, but you shouldn't use an anchor with name anymore ([the name attribute is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)) - just add an id to the element you want to target

Comment: @Pete I had seen a lot of stuff about that in relation to HTML5, which I am using. I have experimented with <a id=etc, <div id=etc, combining both name and div, but the problem is the same with all of them. I fell back to <a name=etc because it works everywhere else.

Comment: The point is that it is obsolete so although it works now, it may not in future as browsers no longer have to support it - therefore best fix it now rather than your site suddenly stopping working when it is live

Comment: set id instead name ! consider it, ID must be unique

Comment: I appreciate your comments so I've changed to divs and ids throughout the site. And I've edited my question to suit. The trouble is, the question still stands.

Comment: Is there a proper URL for the page you are going to? Shouldn't the `href` value be the slug of the page instead of the filename? Might make a difference.